# Segmented Control enabled on iOS 4.0, but disabled on 3.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've got a segmented control embedded within a TableViewCell:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XFML.jpg

It works fine on my iPhone with iOS 4.2, on iPad with iOS 4.2, but on iPad with iOS 3.2 it fails - the segmented control appears disabled. (I don't know whether the issue appears in iOS 3.1)

Any idea what's going on? I have "enabled" set to true of course..

**Edit**

I create the control in IB, so no code for that. I also tried adding a new (fresh) SegmentedControl onto the TableViewCell and it still doesn't work - so it seems like an issue with a TableViewCell which doesn't forward taps to the child controls?

The same issue happens when I put a Switch onto the TableViewCell.

As for the code - it's nothing special:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GoalCell"
 owner:self options:NULL]; 

cell = nibLoadedCell;

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

Goal* g = [self.goals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.goal = g;
cell.label.text = g.title;
cell.segment.selectedSegmentIndex = g.priority;
```

Comment: could you provide some sample code? e.g. creation, maybe disabled in IB

Comment: can you plz give some more information..

Comment: @iPortable - it's created in IB and not marked as disabled.
@ajay - updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segmented control was placed directly on the UITableViewCell, while it should've been attached as an accessory. After changing this, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding one programmatically otherwise I don't know what to do else.